# What is a lift chart?

Tags: data-visualization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Lift measure in data mining](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/17119/lift-measure-in-data-mining)

What exactly is a lift chart? I am still not sure what the purpose of this chart is. Is it basically to compare a baseline model to a different model? Is it like an ROC curve?