# What is the reason behind lift measure?

Tags: mathematical-statistics

While reviewing some slides I see the following formula for calculating lift (which is defined as "measure of dependent/correlated events"):

$$lift(A,B) = \frac{s(A\cup B)}{s(A)\cdot s(B)}$$

which for this table:

\begin{matrix}
 & A & \overline{A}\\ 
B & 400 & 350 \\ 
\overline{B} & 200 & 50
\end{matrix}

gives the following result: 0.4 / (0.6 * 0.75) = 0.89

and tells that if `lift = 1` then events are independent, if `< 1` negatively correlated and if `> 1` - positively.

I can understand how the calculations are made, but I can not understand the reason behind it and how correlation is connected (wanted to write correlate :-) ) to the number 1.

I have seen a [question here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/17119/lift-measure-in-data-mining) about lift, but it looks to me like a completely different question.

Comment: Link to the slides?

Comment: Can you do more to differentiate your Q? The linked thread provides a lot of info about lift & seems to cover some of this. Are you just wondering how 1 becomes the balance point mathematically?