# Best way to represent trend of binary data

Tags: binary-data, trend

I am trying to create a graph representing a trend in binary value distribution. I thought of my own solution but it somehow doesn't feel right. Here's what I'm trying to convey with my graph:

I have a list of items that are either correct or incorrect, and their order is random. I am comparing a couple of scoring algorithms, where higher score means more certainty that the item is correct. So when the list of items is sorted by score, items at the high-score end of the list should have higher correct frequency.

My graph: It would be a 2-axis graph, where x-axis would be increasing score values and y-axis would be correct/incorrect values. The graph itself would be a series of points and their trend line. How steeply the trend line rises would indicate how good is the algorithm at guessing correct items.

The graph feels a bit weird to me, especially the 2 value y-axis, but I can't think of anything better. Is the graph okay or is there a better way to represent the data?

Comment: How about putting time on the x-axis and aggregate score trends on the y-axis?

Comment: Time? I don't collect any time data, so I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Then how can you have a trend? Trends are defined by time, are they not?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, english is not my first language and I'm not very familiar with the terminology. What I mean is a linear trendline that you can create in excel and it can be created on basically any x-y graph

Comment: No problem. What's the issue with this visualization as you've described it? Seems ok to me.

Comment: I guess the y axis seems kind odd to me. All the points will be either at very top or very bottom of the graph, so it almost seems kind of redundant. I just wondered if there was a better way to represent it.

Comment: Sounds like you might want to look at the concept of lift: (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lift_(data_mining)) and (http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/17119/lift-measure-in-data-mining).

Comment: @wayne is definitely on to something there. Following on that suggestion, one approach might be to create deciles or ventiles based on partitioning the ranked scores into groups and examining the relationship between the groupings and the actual averages of the raw binary data. If there is "lift," then the relationship you seek should be represented.

Comment: Yeah, that definitely looks like something I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Now that it looks like the direction you might want to go, I've moved my comment to an answer so you can accept it and so it's easier to find for others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you might want to look at the concept of [lift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lift_(data_mining)). Here's [another thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/17119/lift-measure-in-data-mining) on Cross Validated that shows a lift chart in the accepted answer.

The Wikipedia entry first mentions a lift over random selection, but ultimately you'll probably want to look at a lift over the process that is currently used -- which probably isn't random, and therefore sets a higher bar.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are dealing with only binary data, I would do Receiver Operating Characteristic curve ([ROC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic)) analysis (which by the way is related to lift analysis).

ROC is a chart of sensitivity (y-axis) vs 1-specificity (x-axis) and is quite common in the medical literature.

In your case, you would construct your ROC out of `n` classifiers and you would label each point by the name of the classifier (like the image).  The closer you are to the upper left, the better your classifier is (see wikipedia image below).  Since you have a bunch of random classifiers, I imagine many will be below the 1:1 line

[image: ROC Space from Wikipedia]